# How to create an object with a parameter

Tags: javascript

I want to create an object dynamically. 
What I'd like to have is

```
function create(s){
    const obj = { 
        s : [1,2,3]
    }
}

create("hello");
```

This means my object would look like

```
{
    hello : [1, 2, 3]
};
```

Long term usage would mean my object would become

```
{
    football: [1,2,3],
    hockey: {},
    etc: []
}
```

I am unable to achieve this. Instead, the function `create` renders the variable name as the string, not the value of the variable. As such, the output is

```
{
    s : [1,2,3]
}
```

What do I need to do so I can create my object dynamically based upon the argument I pass in?

Comment: whare are the other properties coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square brackets for a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```
function create(s){
    const obj = { 
        [s] : [1,2,3]
    }
    return obj;
}
```

```js
function create(s){
    const obj = { 
        [s] : [1,2,3]
    }
    return obj;
}
console.log(create("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

since JavaScript object property names (keys) can only be strings or Symbols, when you write `{temp: 1}` here JS will automatically convert it to `'temp'`.

To achieve dynamic keys You can do like this:

```js
function create(s){
    const obj = { 
        [s] : [1,2,3]
    }
    return obj
}

const output = create("hello")
console.log(output)
```

Here I am using `[]` around the keys to treat the key as a variable and not string.